# Unisex Comfort Room Java Advanced Multi Threading

Tags: java, windows, multithreading

Good day everyone!

I need help in helping me solve my java multi threaded problem
it's a Unisex Comfort Room the problem is to;

1. Create A Comfort Room Unisex
2. A male can enter if male is present(vise versa)
3. If male is using female can't enter (vise versa)
4. Fair Usage
5. NO STARVATION

So far I came up something close but i have a problem on fair usage, the male using woman can't enter and the starvation. I need help on this.!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Try2 extends Thread {

    public static Semaphore USERS = new Semaphore(0);
    public static Semaphore PUBLIC_CR = new Semaphore(0);
    public static Semaphore USAGE = new Semaphore(1);

    public static final int LIST = 3;
    public static int a = 0;
    public static int c = 0;

    public static int VACANCY = LIST;

    class MEN extends Thread {

        int iD;
        boolean notUsed = true;

        public MEN(int i) {
            iD = i;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (notUsed) {
                try {
                    USAGE.acquire();
                    if (VACANCY > 0) {
                        System.out.println("MALE " + this.iD + " Is USING");
                        VACANCY--;
                        USERS.release();
                        USAGE.release();
                        try {
                            PUBLIC_CR.acquire();
                            notUsed = false;
                            this.USING_THE_CR();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    } else {
                        USAGE.release();
                        notUsed = false;
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        }

        public void USING_THE_CR() {
            System.out.println("MALE " + this.iD + " is done USING the Comfort Room");
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }

    }

    class WOMEN extends Thread {

        int iD;
        boolean notUsed = true;

        public WOMEN(int i) {
            iD = i;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (notUsed) {
                try {
                    USAGE.acquire();
                    if (VACANCY > 0) {
                        System.out.println("FEMALE " + this.iD + " Is USING");
                        VACANCY--;
                        USERS.release();
                        USAGE.release();
                        try {
                            PUBLIC_CR.acquire();
                            notUsed = false;
                            this.USING_THE_CR();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    } else {

                        USAGE.release();
                        notUsed = false;
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        }

        public void USING_THE_CR() {
            System.out.println("FEMALE " + this.iD + " is DONE USING the Comfort Room");
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }

    }

    class BATHROOM extends Thread {

        public BATHROOM() {
        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {  // runs in an infinite loop
                try {
                    USERS.acquire();
                    USAGE.release();
                    VACANCY++;
                    PUBLIC_CR.release();
                    USAGE.release();
                    this.USING();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        }

        public void USING() {
            System.out.println("The Comfort Room is occupied");
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Try2 BR = new Try2();
        BR.start();  // Let the simulation begin
    }

    public void run() {
        BATHROOM b = new BATHROOM();  //WORKING THREADS ON BATHROOM
        b.start();

        /* THIS WILL GENERATE THE USERS*/
        for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) {

            Random random = new Random();
            int temp = random.nextInt(2);
            if (temp == 0) {
                a++;

                MEN m = new MEN(a);
                m.start();

            } else {
                c++;
                WOMEN w = new WOMEN(c);
                w.start();

            }

            try {
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure you really need three threads, but, you need some kind of queue (men and woman).  Then you need some kind of controller that would determine who can enter and who can't.  You might also need some kind of "arrival" time associated with each individual, so that you're not keeping people waiting to longer (ie, the longest waiting person should be preference).  You could also use some kind of average counter to try and determine fairness when two people have being waiting the same about of time...

Comment: You probably don't need different classes called MEN and WOMEN.  They're very alike in terms of what they actually do.

Comment: I think you need to wait for man, till it gets room. instead of sleep you should use notify-wait mechanism.

Comment: @MadProgrammer what should I use for time arrival? i try to use sleep but it just made the whole thread sleep.

Comment: What I would have is a controller thread that has two queues, one male, one female. In would then have, at least, one other thread that generated people and added them to the controllers queues. This/these would be able to sleep themselves for a random period  of time

Comment: @MadProgrammer when should the random sleeping time take it's place ? The two queues would have been good, But, it's not easy I need to consider the rules of fairness. if there is two queues I would not know who's turn it is Male or Female,well if queues were the CR still i don't know how time takes place.

Comment: What ever is generating the "next" person would sleep at random intervals.  This would allow you to start with just two threads.  One a producer, which generates a random person and adds them to the correct queue and one the controller which determines who should go next.  This is why you need to keep the arrival time of each person. You would need a counter of the number males and females that have used the facilities (maybe normalised so it's more fair) and try and keep this in balance as best you can.

Comment: You may also need a thread per person using the facilities, so that you can have a random delay while they are using the facilities, just to make it more interesting ;)

Comment: that's it, I need a thread per person to delay, Thank you. but how would i do it with my queue, can I create threads using my controller thread. Is it posible to have arraylist of threads?

Comment: @MadProgrammer or do i need an array to do an thread per person ?

Comment: Each "generator" thread should be place an new item it a central queue (or queues, one for each gender), then the controller should be querying this to determine how best to run, is one longer than the other, is the person at the head being waiting a long time, etc...